# Create a Subquery with two external references

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, join, subquery

Im trying to solve an exercise and im having an error when trying to put to external references in a subquery.
The tables are the following:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.SONGS
(
id_song int  IDENTITY(1,1) primary key,
id_album int,
name varchar(50),
price numeric(20,2)
)

CREATE TABLE dbo.PURCHASE
(
id_song int,
id_user int,
price numeric(20,2),
date datetime
)
```

Of course id_song is an FK to SONGS
Songs have a price but the users can buy them for higher or lower price.

The excercise asks to get the highest difference between a purchase and the price of an song for each song. What I have done so far is the following:

```
SELECT SO.name,
        (SELECT MAX(ABS(SO.price-PU.price)) 
         FROM PURCHACE PU WHERE PU.id_song=SO.ID_SONG) diff
        FROM SONGS SO
```

But that is returning an error.

Msg 8124, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Multiple columns are specified in an aggregated expression containing an outer reference. If an expression being aggregated contains an outer reference, then that outer reference must be the only column referenced in the expression

Any suggestions?

Sorry for my english is not my native language.
Thanx in advenced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a simple `max` `group by` should work:

```
select
    so.name,
    max(so.price-pu.price) diff
from dbo.songs so
    inner join dbo.purchase pu
        on pu.id_song = so.id_song
group by
    so.name
```

Comment: Well sir DID work! THANX... still dont understand the subquery and outer references but thats ok

Comment: You are quite welcome sir! :)

What you see with parenthesis here is a aggregate function: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258901(v=SQL.80).aspx

A subquery is like a regular query, but it is executed against every record of the outer query:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213252(v=SQL.80).aspx